# H.265 and Opus in Mp4 container - is it possible?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, mp4, matroska, h.265

I have an MKV file with HEVC video and OPUS audio. It plays great in all players. The problem is that I need it to be streamable. When VLC plays an MKV from the web, it first downloads it and then plays it.

So is there any way to put h.265 and opus in the mp4 container with the moov atom at the beginning of the mp4 file, so that it can start playing without needing to download the whole file?

I tried to do that with several programs, but without success. When using cloudconvert.com I get the error "Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument".

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled over a [commit](https://git.xiph.org/?p=flac.git;a=commitdiff;h=4bbd73a854f47eaf0f776c01d7cf6d0c21639e74) about a draft for flac-in-mp4 which mentioned [opus-in-mp4](https://wiki.xiph.org/Mp4Opus), which means it's not possible yet but it may be in the future.

Comment: I test it with ts and it works "I did 8k transcofing and the sound works" part of my code  `-c:v libx265 -preset veryfast -vb 140k -c:a libopus -b:a 12k -vbr on -compression_level 10 -frame_duration 60 -application audio`

Answer (score 0):

yes, it works

```sh
# ffmpeg 4.4
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:a opus -strict -2 -c:v copy opus.mp4
```